# What IS a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I've seen many challenges get marked as duplicates on this stack. Most I see as fair, some, not so much.

What qualifies as a duplicate question?

Consider challenges where:

- Entries from `a` will be valid for `b` , and entries from `b` will be valid for `a`
- Entries from `a` will be valid for `b` , but entries from `b` are **not** valid for `a`
- Entries from `a` will **not** be valid for `b`, but the challenges are similar in structure and rules.

Comment: This qualifies as a duplicate. Nice example. :P Also, if you don't think the linked question completely answers your question, add a comment over there. There's no need for a 2nd question.